# How to sort the query result by the number of specific column in ACCESS SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

For example:

This is the original result

Alpha      Beta 
A             1 
B             2 
B             3 
C             4

After Order by the number of Alpha, this is the result I want

Alpha      Beta 
B             2 
B             3 
A             1 
C             4

I tried to use GroupBy and OrderBy, but ACCESS always ask me to include all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is 'B' placed before 'A' ? I don't understand this order..

Any way, doesn't seem like you need a group by, not from your data sample, but for your desired result you can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.alpha,t.beta FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.alpha = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
         t.aplha, 
         t.beta
```

**EDIT:** Use this query:

```
SELECT t.alpha,t.beta FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN(SELECT s.alpha,count(*) as cnt
           FROM YourTable s 
           GROUP BY s.alpha) t2
 ON(t.aplha = t2.alpha)
ORDER BY t2.cnt,t.alpha,t.beta
```

Comment: Sagi, because there are 2 B's records and only 1 A's and C's record. So that I want to sort the data by the order of record number.

Answer (score 1):

The query counts number of rows for every distinct Alpha and sorts. General Sql, tweak for ACCESS if needed.

```
SELECT t1.alpha,t1.beta 
FROM  t t1
JOIN ( 
  SELECT t2.alpha, count(t2.*) AS n FROM t t2 GROUP BY t2.alpha
) t3 ON t3.alpha = t1.alpha
ORDER BY t3.n, t1.alpha, t1.beta
```